# How to ensure the latest two files are copied with matching dates using powershell?

Tags: excel, powershell, date, matching

I am using Powershell to copy two files into a drive. These files are created everyday, however sometimes one file is updated and the other does not. How do I ensure that the latest files are copied and the dates match. i.e if File A is as of 26.6.19 and File B is as of 26.6.19 copy these two. However, if File A is as of 26.6.19 but File b is as of 25.6.19 then I will be required to use File A as of 25.6.19 and vice versa.

I have tried using the creation date but this is where my problem is since the dates could be different

$bak_path = "File Path"
get-childitem -path $bak_path -Filter "File A*.csv_AABBCC" |

```
where-object { -not $_.PSIsContainer } | 

  Sort-Object $_.CreationTime |

select-object -last 1 | 


copy-item -Destination File Location
```

get-childitem -path $bak_path -Filter "File B*.csv_AABBCC" |

```
where-object { -not $_.PSIsContainer } | 

  Sort-Object $_.CreationTime |

select-object -last 1 |    

copy-item -Destination File Location
```

Comment: Any one able to help me :(

Comment: help please really stuck on this last hurdle

Comment: please help me someone

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT at 11am GMT 28/06/2019**

Ok so based on the notes of our converstion I've tried to replicate your environment.

```
Get-ChildItem E:\test1 

Directory: E:\test1

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       27/06/2019     13:54          11170 PRM_cashExtract_20190627t10045.csv_ATF03305
-a----       27/06/2019     14:02          48682 PRM_cashExtract_20190627t10045.csv_ATF04251
-a----       27/06/2019     13:54          11170 PRM_cashExtract_20190628t10045.csv_ATF03305
-a----       27/06/2019     14:02          48682 PRM_cashExtract_20190628t10045.csv_ATF04251
-a----       27/06/2019     14:07          44582 PRM_posExtract_20190627t10045.csv_ATF04251
-a----       27/06/2019     14:07           1079 PRM_transExtract_20190627t10045.csv_ATF03305
-a----       27/06/2019     14:18        1587853 PRM_transExtract_20190627t10045.csv_ATF04251
```

I then ran these commands to just go for the two files you're after based on naming convention and a creation date within the last 24/47 hours

```
$date = ( Get-Date ).AddDays( -1 ).DayOfYear
$bak_path = Get-ChildItem FILEPATH | where { ( $_.Name -match "_ATF04251" ) -and ( $_.Name -notmatch "trans" ) } | Select Name, FullName, @{ n="CreationTime" ; e={ ( Get-Date $_.CreationTime ).DayOfYear } } | sort CreationTime
```

This gave me:

```
$bak_path
Name                                        FullName                                             CreationTime
----                                        --------                                             ------------
PRM_cashExtract_20190627t10045.csv_ATF04251 E:\test1\PRM_cashExtract_20190627t10045.csv_ATF04251          178
PRM_posExtract_20190627t10045.csv_ATF04251  E:\test1\PRM_posExtract_20190627t10045.csv_ATF04251           178
PRM_cashExtract_20190628t10045.csv_ATF04251 E:\test1\PRM_cashExtract_20190628t10045.csv_ATF04251          179
```

So it's picked up three files, two from yesterday, and one from today.

This final line here groups the files by creation date, and if the file count is two or higher, it copies them across to your destination.

```
$bak_path | Group-Object { $_.CreationTime } | where { ( $_.Count -ge 2 ) -and ( $_.Group.CreationTime -ge $date ) } | foreach { Copy-Item $_.Group.FullName -Destination DESTINATION }
```

Comment: ahh great this is definitely on the right lines. Is there a way we can just filter for the files called cash_ and pos_ as there are tons of files in the folder

Comment: It has brought back cash and pos. Cash as of today and Pos as of yesterday as there wasnt any new Pos file brought in today.  I can work around the several additional files being brought in by removing all apart from my two but the dates need to be consistant

Comment: Hiya, sorry I was on leave yesterday. Yeah sure. In the `where` just add another filter like this `-and ( $_.Name -match "cash" ) -and ( $_.Name -match "pos" )`

Comment: If it brings in both yesterday and today's results and tries to copy them both... if this is a problem (is it?), then throw in `| select -first 1` between the end of the `where` filter and `foreach`. like this. `( $_.Group.CreationTime -ge $date ) } | select -first 1 | foreach { Copy-Item`

Answer (score 0):

`Get-ChildItem` has a parameter `-File` to list only the files, so you don't have to use `| where-object { -not $_.PSIsContainer }`.

You want to get the *latest common* version of FileA and FileB and then copy them to your `$destination`, so here's the code.

**Updated Code**

```
$lastA = Get-ChildItem -Path $bak_path -File -Filter "File A*.csv_AABBCC" | Sort-Object -Property {$_.CreationTime.Day} -Descending | select -First 1
$lastB = Get-ChildItem -Path $bak_path -File -Filter "File B*.csv_AABBCC" | Sort-Object -Property {$_.CreationTime.Day} -Descending | select -First 1
$lowest = [math]::Min($lastA.CreationTime.Day, $lastB.CreationTime.Day)

Get-ChildItem -Path $bak_path -File -Filter "File A*.csv_AABBCC" | where-object {$_.Creationtime.day -eq $lowest -and $_.CreationTime.Month -eq $lastA.Creationtime.month} | copy-item -Destination $destination
Get-ChildItem -Path $bak_path -File -Filter "File B*.csv_AABBCC" | where-object {$_.Creationtime.day -eq $lowest -and $_.CreationTime.Month -eq $lastB.Creationtime.month} | copy-item -Destination $destination
```

1- I'm getting the last created time of both FileA and FileB.

2- Get the lowest date between them (to make sure both FileA and FileB has the newest common version)

3- Copy the files to the destination.

Comment: Thanks I seem to go into an issue: At line:8 char:104
+ ... | where-object $_.Creationtime.day -eq $lowest | copy-item -Destination $destina ...
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Where-Object], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WhereObjectCommand      - not sure why

Comment: great so now they pull through, however not the right dates. they have pulled in the same day but not month. 12.06.19 and 12.04.19. There are definitely latest files for today for both

Comment: any luck with modifying the code? nothing seems to be happening here

Comment: sorry i've been offline; I want to know something, may your file (A or B) not be written for more than 5 days? i mean FileA at 20.6.2019 and FileB at 26.6.2019, can this happen?

Comment: ahh thought id be stuck for life. It is very unlikely since they are both sent out everyday - sometimes one, for some unknown reason, gets stuck and then thats why i cannot use my code above

Comment: Say that this updated code ran and let's celebrate :P

Comment: This code actually caused a crazy error and did not work :( I am so sad

Comment: okay - i managed to work out that issue. the code now pulls in the two files however File A is @ 31.3.19 and File B is @ 31.05.19 - bit confused as to why it has come out this way

Comment: I'm sorry i have no more thing to do with this, i created different files and tried the code, and it's running as you want. I don't know where's the problem :( Hope you manage to find the solution.

Comment: ah thank you for your help thus far. The files are bringing them from different dates back in March - guess its too tricky to automate :/